# How to get Image name set to ImageButton programatically?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have taken an imageButton in my application as follows:

```
<LinearLayout >
<ImageButton 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
android:id="@id/fund_transfer_btn" 
android:background="@null" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:longClickable="true" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/fund_transfer" 
android:hint="Fund Transfer" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Above ImageView has a default image set to it as mentioned in `android:src="@drawable/fund_transfer"` . Now  this  image is changes dynamically say on click of ABC button it changes to "abc.png" like:

```
ImageButton imgbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fund_transfer_btn);
imgbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc);
```

and some anather button click changes it to "xyz.png":

```
ImageButton imgbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fund_transfer_btn);
imgbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.xyz);
```

Now  On click of Button "GetImageName" i want to get image name whichever is set currently to this imageButton and toast it.

But whatever i searched not giving me a image name.

SO please can anyone tell me  if there is any method or way that can give me a name of the image set to button.

thanks in advance . .

Comment: sounds hackie, may I ask why yo need to know it ? what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ blackbelt . .Actually I am doin reverse engineering of an app in of which i need to change the images to the images having relative name . Say if current image of button is abc.png then i have to change it to abc_myImage.png . .